# IIS fails to install on Windows 7

Tags: iis

I keep getting the error message when attempting to install IIS on Windows 7

```
"An error has occurred. Not all the features were successfully changed."
```

The iis7.log contains shows...

```
[07/17/2013 12:48:05] "C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /install SharedLibraries
[07/17/2013 12:48:05] Successfully added IIS_IUSRS ACE to DACL at %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue.
[07/17/2013 12:48:05] < !!FAIL!! > Failed to acquire the NetFrameworkConfigurationKey key container context (result=0x8007054f)
[07/17/2013 12:48:05] < !!FAIL!! > Install of component SharedLibraries result=0x8007054f
[07/17/2013 12:48:05] < !!FAIL!! > COMPONENT::ExecuteCommand result=0x8007054f
```

I have tried doing a clean boot (disabling non-microsoft services) but this has not helped.
Has anyone got anything to suggest?

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: Seems like an .net framework error? Which version do you use? Maybe try to reinstall .net framework

Comment: I would post this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). You will get a better response rate.

Comment: Can you please specify of Windows 7 version?

Comment: @ChiragVidani - The version of Windows 7 wouldn't be the cause of this error.

Comment: I have tried re-installing .Net Framework - but I still get the same error.

Comment: @enigmasck - i am trying to install iis on a desktop rather than a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs due to unstable changes in Microsoft .Net Framework follow these steps to fix it out.

**Step1:**
Remove Microsoft .Net Framework under Turn Windows features on or off.

[image]

**Step2:**
Again Install IIS 6 or 7 under Turn Windows features on or off.

[image]

**Step3:**
Again install Microsoft .Net Framework under Turn Windows features on or off.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error while I was installing the IIS on a windows 7 , 32 bit machine. 
I've tried almost all the solution that I found in many websites. 
In order to get rid of this error you can do a **repair** of the OS. it will solve the issue permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7

Try this,

run cmd as Admin.

Unistall all iis.

```
 start /w pkgmgr.exe /uu:IIS-WebServerRole;WAS-WindowsActivationService
```

Reinstall iis and normaly it's work

Alain

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was just able to successfully install IIS on Windows 7 Sp1 (64bit) after having the same problem and 2 days of internet searches. I hope I can help someone with the same problem.

After running the same command **"C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\iissetup.exe" /install SharedLibraries"** and monitoring it using ProcessMonitor, it appeared that the installer is not able to write to the folder **"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"**

I renamed **MachineKeys** to **MachineKeys_old** and reinstalled the IIS feature and it completed without any errors.